# Add new property in Realm.io (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, realm

i'm testing Realm.io in Swift and i'm using the site's documentation for all the help, but now i'm stuck.

I had a simple class to add titles to UITableView with no problems.

```
class CellTitle: RLMObject {
    dynamic var title = ""
}
```

Now i'm trying to add a second property but using the documentation for Migrations / Adding more version always fails.

> For testing i change the class to

```
class CellTitle: RLMObject {
    dynamic var title = ""
    dynamic var subtitle = ""
}
```

> And i add to AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions... the
>   following code

```
    RLMRealm.setSchemaVersion(1, forRealmAtPath: RLMRealm.defaultRealmPath(),
        withMigrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {

                migration.enumerateObjects(CellTitle.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                    newObject["subtitle"] = ""
                }
            }
    })
```

> And always get the error:

**Migration is required for object type 'CellTitle' due to the following errors:
- Property 'subtitle' has been added to latest object model.'**

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Have you tried setting a higher schema version, such as 2?

Comment: According to documentation, the value must be one because it's my first property change. I tried 2 as value but still the same (correctly i think).

Comment: did you also change the `1` in the conditional?

Comment: Are you sure that you're setting the schema version before opening the realm for the first time?

Comment: Yes, the realm opens in another controller - with a button save

Comment: can you send your code privately to help@realm.io, I also tried to reproduce and it was working for me

Comment: I'll send to you the project - it's a test project with some libraries for testing.

Comment: I just send it you via dropbox... Thank you.

Comment: Thanks the Realm.io team! My mistake was that i was calling allObjects before the viewDidLoad() and realm was opening before didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: Good to hear you got it working!

Comment: @DimitriosKalaitzidis http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34277061/swift-realm-property-has-been-added-to-latest-object-model-migration