# Swift Realm Property '*' has been added to latest object model MIGRATION

Tags: swift, migration, realm

I have added new array attribute to the RLMObject and

```
public class Student: RLMObject {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var resultList = RLMArray(objectClassName:Result.className())
}

public class Result: RLMObject {
}
```

ERROR Log:

> Migration is required for object type 'Student' due to the following
>   errors:
>   - Property 'resultList' has been added to latest object model.

TRY Failed:

```
let configuration:RLMRealmConfiguration = RLMRealmConfiguration.defaultConfiguration()

migration.enumerateObjects(Student.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
    newObject!["resultList"] = RLMArray(objectClassName: Result.className())
}
```

EDIT:

```
  let configuration:RLMRealmConfiguration = RLMRealmConfiguration.defaultConfiguration()
    print("Realm db current version: \(configuration.schemaVersion)")
    configuration.schemaVersion = 1
    configuration.migrationBlock = {(migration:RLMMigration, oldSchemaVersion: UInt64) in
        print("Realm db migration start")
        if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
            print("Schema version: 1 - Rename fields")
            migration.enumerateObjects(Student.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                newObject!["creationDate"] = oldObject!["createdAt"]
                newObject!["modifiedDate"] = oldObject!["updatedAt"]
            }
        }
        print("Realm db migration finish")
    }
    RLMRealmConfiguration.setDefaultConfiguration(configuration)
    let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
```

SOLUTION:

update your version to +1

```
configuration.schemaVersion += 1
```

Comment: You seem to use quite old version of Realm?

Comment: Where is the `migration` object coming from? Do you make any changes to your configuration?

Comment: @marius updated my full code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to incremented your `schemaVersion` and provide a `migrationBlock` on your `RLMRealmConfiguration`. In there you can migrate tables. But you don't need that in your specific case here. The addition of properties can be handled automatically. You'll still need an empty block.

```
let config = RLMRealmConfiguration.defaultConfiguration()
config.schemaVersion = 1
config.migrationBlock = { (migration, oldSchemaVersion) in
    // nothing to do
}
RLMRealmConfiguration.setDefaultConfiguration(config)
```

Comment: Thanks @marius, Edited to my full code.. can you please point me the false?

Comment: Please note though that it won't be sufficient for the next schema changes to just increment the schemaVersion by one. It must be higher than the stored version in the database, so it might make sense to store there an absolute number.

Comment: If you're still in development, you probably want to reset the simulator's content and settings instead / remove your app and start over from scratch. It will make it a whole lot easier if you have only to worry about migrations between schema versions, which were actually deployed.